# Value prints outside of the echo

Tags: php

My code validates and returns the custom field value. However, I can't get the value to return inside of the anchors.

Here is the code:

```
<div id="meta_mblink">
<?
if(function_exists('get_custom_field_data')) {
echo '<a href="'.get_custom_field_data('mblink', true).'"></a>';
} 
?>
</div>
```

This is what is returned:

```
<div id="meta_mblink">
http://yada.yadayada.yada:5000/pop.jsp?id=1711436
<a href=""></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would code this:

```
$url = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'mblink', true );
if ( ! empty( $url ) ) {
    print '<a href="' . esc_url( $url ) . '">MBLINK</a>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the problem is the custom function `get_custom_field_data()`. Can you post the function definition?

Most likely, the second argument corresponds to whether or not to echo the result. Try changing it to `false`?

**EDIT**

[Here's an example of this function being defined in a tutorial](http://perishablepress.com/press/2008/12/22/wordpress-custom-fields-tips-tricks/):

```
<?php function get_custom_field_data($key, $echo = false) {
    global $post;
    $value = get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, true);
    if($echo == false) {
        return $value;
    } else { 
        echo $value;
    }
}
?>
```

I would recommend just using `get_post_meta()`, rather than using a wrapper function.

Comment: Ah hah! That was the situation I had that I was trying to recall in my above (or below) answer. I had an echo in an echo. I was struggling to remember why I had that problem. http://wordpress.org/support/topic/php-post_comments_feed_link-wont-stay-inside-enclosing-html?replies=3 Was the old forum thread where I got help for it.

Comment: bennett yes that's the function I was using. So I've modified the function:
      `echo '<a href="'.get_post_meta($post->ID, 'mblink', true).'"></a>';`

but now nothing returns. I also tried to add a 'global $post;` before the echo but no luck. I dont understand why that wrapper function works but the get_post_meta() by itself does not.

Comment: @glu great! So does it work?

Comment: yes. it shows in the source but not on the page. i'm assuming that's because there is no text for the link. however, when i add text to the argument like this: `echo '<a href="'.get_post_meta($post->ID, 'mblink', true).'">MBLINK</a>';` it returns this `<div id="meta_mblink">
 <a href="">MBLINK</a> </div>`

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the second parameter to FALSE, (or just leave it blank) in the get_custom_field_data function.  Do this:

```
<div id="meta_mblink">
 <?php
 if(function_exists('get_custom_field_data')) {
 ?>
 <a href="<?php echo get_custom_field_data('mblink'); ?>"></a>
 <?php
 }
  ?> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="meta_mblink">
 <?php
 if(function_exists('get_custom_field_data')) {
 ?>
 <a href="<?php echo get_custom_field_data('mblink', true); ?>"></a>
 <?php
 }
  ?> 
</div>
```

Maybe something like that? I recall having issues with echos busting out of html before and doing something like this worked for me